# Firebase Auth issue occurring only in safari, fine in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase auth to handle user authentication on my website, however there are continuity issues when moving from page to page. This issue is only present when run using Safari. In Google Chrome, it works perfectly fine.

When a user signs in on "login.html", onAuthStateChanged():

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){

    if (user){

    //User is signed in
    console.log("And now we're on the page");
    console.log(user2);

    //Lead User to Main ShareHub Page
    setTimeout(function (){

        window.location.replace("./td/AuthStoreTrans.html");

        }, 10000);


    } else {

    }
});
```

is called, and the page successfully loads the main page "AuthStoreTrans.html". The user is still signed in on the main page, and is able to perform ant actions they need to. However, when the user clicks the log out button:

```
btnLogout.addEventListener('click', function() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
    // Sign-out successful.
        setTimeout(function (){
            window.location.replace("../login.html");
        }, 5000);
    }).catch(function(error) {
    // An error happened.
    console.log(error);
    });
    console.log('User signed out');

 });
```

The user is supposedly signed out and is sent back to the login page, where for some reason a user is still found to be logged in, and onAuthStateChanged() is performed again, sending the user back to the main page where they are still logged out, and no data loads. I'm not sure if I'm missing something essential- but if I close out of the browser and reload the login page, then the user is successfully logged out, and it does not redirect to the main page.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Will be hard to tell without a repro. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Wondering if you ever got this figured out since it's been a few months. Thanks.